# how to get all rows distinct which has date closed with today

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one table in SQL  in this form:

```
id      Name      Date
----------------------------
1       john      04/05/2014
2       andi      12/05/2014
3       mark      05/08/2014
4       sofie     05/11/2014
5       john      12/12/2014
5       mark      15/12/2014
```

and i want to select  data in this form "distinct"

```
id      Name      Date
---------------------------
1       john     12/12/2014
2       mark     15/12/2014
3       andi     12/05/2014
```

Comment: which DBMS ? MySQL ? you want distinct name ?

Comment: @JetmirMorina, on **what criterion** would you exclude `sofie` from the output?  How would `mark` and `andi` switch IDs?  This raises more doubts than it answers and must really be clarified (not a problem of English, either!-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may want

```
SELECT name, MAX(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

However, from your example it's impossible to infer on what criterion you'd exclude `sofie` (and what does a **duplicate** `id` mean in your example table -- `id` is normally used to denote a unique identifier).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-- sample data
create table #tbl (id int, name nvarchar(20), [date] date);
insert into #tbl (id, name, [date]) values
(1, 'john', '2014-05-04'),
(2, 'andi', '2014-05-12'),
(3, 'mark', '2014-08-05'),
(4, 'sofie', '2014-11-05'),
(5, 'john', '2014-12-12'),
(5, 'mark', '2014-12-15');

-- solution
with ranked as
(
    select id, name, [date]
    , row_number() over(partition by name order by datediff(day, [date], getdate())) [rank]
    from #tbl
)
select id, name, [date] from ranked where [rank] = 1;

-- cleanup
drop table #tbl;
```

Result

```
ID  NAME    DATE
----------------------
2   andi    2014-05-12
5   john    2014-12-12
5   mark    2014-12-15
4   sofie   2014-11-05
```

This solution ranks original dataset by name and in case when there are the same names ranks them by count of days between today and [date]. So the result dataset consists of rows with the unique names and the rows with names which [date] is closest to today.

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e04229/3)

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM <table_name> t1
WHERE t1.date = (SELECT MAX(t2.date)
            FROM <table_name> t2
            WHERE t2.name = t1.name)
```